# How to control velocity of a key event

Tags: java, events, keyboard

I want to control a parameter through my arrow keys when i press up the parameter is incremented by one and when i press down it should decrement, but what its really happening is that when i press the up arrow key the key event is called a lot of times, in function of the time the key is pressed. Just a fast click makes the value increment like 10 times. My goal its to make the value increment only once per click or at least slow down the velocity of the key event. Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    currentParam++;
                    if(currentParam>=90)
                        currentParam = 45;
                    System.out.println(currentParam);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of flag to indicate that the event has been handled. This should be reset once the key is released.

A common method is to either use a series of `boolean` flags or a `Map` keyed to each type of key or a `List` which contains all the currently active keys.

Which you chose will depend on the rest of your program.

You really should avoid using `KeyListener`s, they are troublesome and fickle.  A better solution is to use the key bindings API, take a look at [How to use key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)